# How to solve error 415 from angular 9 spring boot app?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I have the following code from angular 9 app, it's a post method which send many fields:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

return this.http.post(`${AppComponent.API}/Trip/Add`, JSON.stringify(trip), httpOptions);
```

This is the corresponding rest controller:

```
@PostMapping("/Trip/Add")       
    public Integer addFund(@RequestBody Trip trip) {                    
        return tripService.addTrip(trip);               
    }
```

This is the error from browser log:

```
zone-evergreen.js:2952 POST http://localhost:9019/trips/trip/Add 415 "Unsupported Media Type"
```

I've looked at my entity in java and make few field as @JsonIgnore in order get to the buttom
of this without success. Is 415 mean bad mapping or I missing someting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had static final fields which were without @JsonIgnore on them.